# Is char datatype is supported in Liferay service builder

Tags: sql-server-2008, liferay-6

I just want to know is service builder support char data type. We can change the size of varchar by tables.sql file. So if I am using varchar(1) then it will work perfectly or not.
I have already created tables so I have to use that one. I didn't use char in service.xml, is it possible or we have any alternative.
Liferay 6.1
tomcat 7
Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

One options is to modify [com.liferay.portal.tools.servicebuilder.ServiceBuilder](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/tools/servicebuilder/ServiceBuilder.java) class as it currently doesn't support CHAR datatype. Check this forum post for your reference: https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/21873171. It is not easy way though!

Hope this helps!

Comment: After reading the provided link by you, I will let you know that it is working or not. Thanks for reply